# Finding a successor in a binary search tree in $O(1)$

Tags: data-structures, search-trees

In my algorithms course I have learned about the binary search tree and its functions add, find and remove.
I have also learned about how to find the successor and the predecessor in a balanced binary search tree, but they are both $O(\log n)$ I think.

Now, I have been thinking, how can I change a given binary search tree so that I could find any given node's successor in $O(1)$ time? The other operations should still run in $O(\log n)$ time.

I have thought about maintaining the tree in a linked list but I am sure that there is a better solution to it.

Comment: This is a commen exercise problem. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We want to help you with your specific problems, not just do your (home-)work. However, as it is we don't know what this problem is and thus how to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: disagree with close on this as unclear. the question is clear. also wondering if precomputing a table or cache-like structure is included in the cost? tables/caches have a cost to compute but after computed can be more efficient to merely access...